# How to normalize a Counter and combine 2 normalized Counters? - python

Tags: python, list, counter

Firstly, I have two list of strings:

```
['abc','abc','def','jkl']
['abc','def','def','pqr', 'pr', 'foo', 'bar']
```

And then I need counters of the lists that are normalized such that the sum of the values in each counter equals 1:

```
Counter({'abc': 0.8164965809277261, 'jkl': 0.4082482904638631, 'def': 0.4082482904638631})
Counter({'abc': 1.1498299142610595, 'def': 1.0749149571305296, 'jkl': 0.4082482904638631, 'pr': 0.3333333333333333, 'bar': 0.3333333333333333, 'pqr': 0.3333333333333333, 'foo': 0.3333333333333333})
```

The normalizing factor is

```
math.sqrt(sum(i*i for i in counter.values()))
```

I've tried the following by iterating throw the counter keys but is there any other way of achieving the say `x+y` Counter?

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> import math
>>> x = Counter(['abc','abc','def','jkl'])
>>> denominator = 1/math.sqrt(sum(math.pow(i,2) for i in x.values()))
>>> for i in x:
...     x[i]*=denominator
... 
>>> x
Counter({'abc': 0.8164965809277261, 'jkl': 0.4082482904638631, 'def': 0.4082482904638631})
>>> y = Counter(['abc','def','def','pqr', 'pr', 'foo', 'bar'])
>>> denominator2 = 1/math.sqrt(sum(math.pow(i,2) for i in y.values()))
>>> for i in y:
...     y[i]*=denominator2
... 
>>> y
Counter({'def': 0.6666666666666666, 'pr': 0.3333333333333333, 'abc': 0.3333333333333333, 'bar': 0.3333333333333333, 'pqr': 0.3333333333333333, 'foo': 0.3333333333333333})
>>> x+y
Counter({'abc': 1.1498299142610595, 'def': 1.0749149571305296, 'jkl': 0.4082482904638631, 'pr': 0.3333333333333333, 'bar': 0.3333333333333333, 'pqr': 0.3333333333333333, 'foo': 0.3333333333333333})
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to sum the values, then divide each count by the sum:

```
total = sum(x.values(), 0.0)
for key in x:
    x[key] /= total
```

By starting the sum with `0.0` we make sure `total` is a floating point value, avoiding the Python 2 floor division behaviour of `/` with integer operands.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> x = Counter(['abc','abc','def','jkl'])
>>> total = sum(x.values(), 0.0)
>>> for key in x:
...     x[key] /= total
... 
>>> x
Counter({'abc': 0.5, 'jkl': 0.25, 'def': 0.25})
>>> y = Counter(['abc','def','def','pqr', 'pr', 'foo', 'bar'])
>>> total = sum(y.values(), 0.0)
>>> for key in y:
...     y[key] /= total
... 
>>> y
Counter({'def': 0.2857142857142857, 'pr': 0.14285714285714285, 'abc': 0.14285714285714285, 'bar': 0.14285714285714285, 'pqr': 0.14285714285714285, 'foo': 0.14285714285714285})
```

If you need to sum the counters, you'd need to re-normalize the resulting counter separately; summing two normalized counters means you have a new counter whole values sum to 2, for example.

Comment: thanks @martijn for the quick answer but i had a typo it should be sum first then sqrt otherwise `sqrt(pow(i,2)) == i` ;P

Comment: @alvas: then the answer is: no, there is no way to use `/` or `*` on all the keys. Only summing and subtraction is defined.

Comment: Replacing the `for` loop with a comprehension is faster: `{k:v/total for k,v in x.iteritems()}`. This will give a plain old `dict` back. But converting back to `Counter` with this method is still faster: `Counter({k:v/total for k,v in x.iteritems()})`. Also @MartijnPieters nice tip with the floating pint starting value in `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

Normalization of a Counter object (`c1`) of a List object (`l1`) is dividing each counts by the total elements in the list that is the lenght of the list (`total`). This is less costly comparing with calculating the total counts in (`c1`) like `sum(c1.values(), 0.0)`.

The following example on the first list given can be used:

```
l1 = ['abc','abc','def','jkl']
c1 = Counter(l1)
# Normalization
total = 1.0 * len(l1) # converting to float to avoid floor division in Python 2.X
for k in c1:
    c1[k] /= total
```