# How can I find relative word frequencies?

Tags: python

Here is the code that I have:

```
for question in questions:
    print('Processing ' + str( question))
    counts = Counter(dataset_final[str(question)])
    print(counts)
```

This prints out something like:

```
Processing 1
Counter({'would': 18, 'think': 12, 'patient': 11, 'condition': 11, 'might': 10, 'increased': 1})

Processing 2
Counter({'cancer': 32, 'condition': 22, 'prostate': 20, 'educational': 1})
```

I want to get the relative word frequency, so I wanted to do something like:

```
for question in questions:
    print("Processing " + str(question))
    counts = Counter(dataset_final[str(question)])
    length = len(dataset_final[str(question)])
    print(counts/length)
```

But I get an error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Counter' and 'int'
```

How can I do that?

edit: i meant relative word frequencies, not normalizing

Comment: Why are you normalising by the length of the counter and not by the max count?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say: relative word frequencies

Comment: So you divide by max count, not by the length?

Comment: i want to divide each count by the number of tokens, which is the length of the counts

Comment: oh wait, it just clicked. i realized what i did.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to normalize a Counter and combine 2 normalized Counters? - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22428842/how-to-normalize-a-counter-and-combine-2-normalized-counters-python)

Answer (score 0):

Let :

```
 count = collections.Counter({'would': 18, 'think': 12, 'patient': 11, 'condition': 11, 'might': 10, 'increased': 1})
```

You can normalize values with a list comprehension:

```
 normalized_count = {w:c/sum(count.values()) for w,c in count.items()}
```

The number of each word count will be divided by the total number of words.

Output:

```
{'would': 0.2857142857142857, 'think': 0.19047619047619047, 'patient': 0.1746031746031746, 'condition': 0.1746031746031746, 'might': 0.15873015873015872, 'increased': 0.015873015873015872}
```